# Batch file that closes 1 application after another specific application has started

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Hello i want my Epic Games Launcher application to close automatically, after the game fortnite.exe has been started.

Can i do this with a batch file?

Comment: you can kill a process with `taskkill`

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This is not enough info for a question on this platform. Please edit your question and write a problem description. What are you doing? What programming language is this - add the relevant tag! For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Questions without source code should usually be asked at https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can firstly get the *program name* of you Epic Games Launcher (I'll call it EGL) **if** it is **not** the batch file. Kill the EGL process by this:

> `taskkill /IM "program name of EGL here" -f -t`

---

If your EGL **is** the *batch that starts* **"fortnite.exe"**, you can simply do it with:

> `start explorer "the path of fortnite\fortnite.exe"`
>
> `exit`

Comment: `Start` used like that expects the first double quoted argument to be a title, as shown in the help, `Start /?`; so your command should be, `Start "TitleString" "Executable Name With Special Characters Like Spaces"`, `Start "" "Executable Name With Special Characters Like Spaces"` or `Start ExecutableNameWithoutSpecialCharactersLikeSpaces`.

Comment: Oh sorry and thanks for reminding me. Let me do a bit of editing.